# Force reload image jsf

Tags: image, jsf-2, browser-cache

I would like to display a graphic image in a jsf web application from a html file that's changing for each run.
The problem is that the displayed image was always the same.

I tried to solve this by generating a random  number at the end of the image name.

```
    public String getImageId () {
    String imageId = ""; 
    int nb = (int)Math.random(); 
    imageId = "?id="+Integer.toString(nb);
    return imageId; 
}
```

Then, I call it in my jsf page

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/Report.html_files/img_0_0_0#{MyBean.imageId}" cacheable="false" />
```

But nothing change.

Do you Have any idea about this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For my application, I
created a Java Servlet that returns a different image
each time, with HTTP header `Cache-Control`
set to prevent caching and I use the servlet URL in my  JSF tag.

I do not think you can dynamically change the image with a URL
to a static file, like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another palliative solution, is force refresh in your browser using the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.